# Log de transações de login MSSQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso de um help, tenho que disponibilizar um login no `MSSQL` a empresa do ERP e meu superior precisa monitorar as transações do tipo `INSERT`, `DELETE` e `UPDATE` que são feitas por eles, no caso os scripts que foram executados nesses tipos de transações.

Exemplos :

```
INSERT INTO tabela001 (id, campo1, campo2) Values (1,'Texto1', 123 )
```

No Log eu guardaria os dados do login, o tipo de transação e o script executado.

Comment: Fiz a pergunta, mas também não sei se é possível.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei de responder uma pergunta semelhante [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/230156/verificar-insert-update-ou-detete-banco-firebird/230239#230239). Você pode trabalhar com [triggers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gatilho_(banco_de_dados)). Cada tabela no banco terá uma trigger para determinada operação (INSERT, DELETE E UPDATE). Através desta é possível obter a informação que você deseja e armazenar em uma tabela (sugestão).

Segue o exemplo de uma trigger do firebird:

```
CREATE TRIGGER au FOR table
  AFTER UPDATE
  POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF RDB$GET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK') IS NULL THEN
  BEGIN
    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', 1);

    ...
    Do your update operations here
    ...

    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', NULL);
  END

  WHEN ANY DO
  BEGIN
    RDB$SET_CONTEXT('USER_TRANSACTION', 'MY_LOCK', NULL);
    EXCEPTION;
  END
END
```

Comment: Vlw @Karan Alves Pereira, uma pena mas no SQL Server não funciona da mesma forma.

Comment: @RicardoSouza a criação da trigger para o sql server é bem semelhante. Acredito que você não terá dificuldades para criá-la. Qualquer coisa avisa. abraço.